# Unable to run Teams toolkit app on my mac

Tags: teams-toolkit

I have a Teams Toolkit App that runs fine on my windows but the same app doesnt run on mac and throws the below error

Error: there is no registered task type 'teamsfx'. Did you miss to install an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?
The below is what I have in the tasks.json file.

I do have the teams toolkit extension installed as well.
Please advise what am I missing.

```
// This file is automatically generated by Teams Toolkit.
// The teamsfx tasks defined in this file require Teams Toolkit version >= 5.0.0.
// See https://aka.ms/teamsfx-tasks for details on how to customize each task.
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Start Teams App Locally",
      "dependsOn": ["Validate prerequisites", "Provision", "Deploy", "Start application"],
      "dependsOrder": "sequence"
    },
    {
      // Check all required prerequisites.
      // See https://aka.ms/teamsfx-tasks/check-prerequisites to know the details and how to customize the args.
      "label": "Validate prerequisites",
      "type": "teamsfx",
      "command": "debug-check-prerequisites",
      "args": {
        "prerequisites": [
          "nodejs", // Validate if Node.js is installed.
          "m365Account", // Sign-in prompt for Microsoft 365 account, then validate if the account enables the sideloading permission.
          "portOccupancy" // Validate available ports to ensure those debug ones are not occupied.
        ],
        "portOccupancy": [
          53000 // tab service port
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      // Create the debug resources.
      // See https://aka.ms/teamsfx-tasks/provision to know the details and how to customize the args.
      "label": "Provision",
      "type": "teamsfx",
      "command": "provision",
      "args": {
        "env": "local"
      }
    },
    {
      // Build project.
      // See https://aka.ms/teamsfx-tasks/deploy to know the details and how to customize the args.
      "label": "Deploy",
      "type": "teamsfx",
      "command": "deploy",
      "args": {
        "env": "local"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "Start application",
      "dependsOn": ["Start frontend"]
    },
    {
      "label": "Start frontend",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "npm run dev:teamsfx",
      "isBackground": true,
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": {
        "pattern": {
          "regexp": "^.*$",
          "file": 0,
          "location": 1,
          "message": 2
        },
        "background": {
          "activeOnStart": true,
          "beginsPattern": ".*",
          "endsPattern": "Compiled|Failed|compiled|failed"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to debug the app on teams but it doesnt work and throws the above error instead

Comment: Try restarting VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting VS Code and open your app. Then check if Teams Toolkit extension has been activated successfully before running your app:

1. Open "Teams Toolkit" output window and check if below message shows. [image]
2. Open "Extension Host" output window and check the logs of "TeamsDevApp.ms-teams-vscode-extension"[image]

If Teams Toolkit has been activated successfully, your app is supposed to work well.